# What is the correct method to follow in chanting Hare Krishna Mahamantra?

Tags: krishna, mantras

What is actually the correct method to chant the Harekrishna Mahamantra? Like what we should follow before chanting of that mantra, and which direction we have to face while chanting the mantra, and how we should end the process of chanting this mantra?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the  'Kali-Santarana-Upanishad', the Mahamantra is mentioned as : Hare Rama Hare Rama ..Hare Hare/ Hare KrishNa Hare KrishNa .. Hare Hare//

> punar  narada¿  papraccha bhagavan ko 'sya vidhir iti | taµ hovåca **nåsya** **vidhir** **iti** |
>   sarvadå çucir açucir vå pa†han **bråhmanah** salokatåµ samîpatåµ sarûpatåµ såyujyam
>   eti | yadåsya ßo¥açakasya sårdha triko†ir japati tadå brahma-hatyåµ tarati |....
>
> **English Translation** (of the relevant part): There is **no rule to be followed** to chant the Mahamantra for the brahmins. They chanting it in pure or impure state attains different forms of mukti like sAlokya, sAmipya, sAjujya etc getting freed from all sins. **This Upanishad also says that chanting  the maantra 'sArdha-Tri-koti-vAra' ie three crores and fifty lakh times in total is required to get the results.**

It is a Veda-mantra and especially specified for the brahmins.So one view is that Mahaprabhu preached it by reversing the order making it chantable by all while keeping everything including the fruits unchanged.Other views say that He compiled it from the Agni-purAna and another from the BrahmAnda -purAna as hypothesised by Dr. Mahmanamavrata Brahmachari. In RadhA-tantra also the Mantra starts with 'Hare Krishna' by the way.According to Mahaprabhu also, no rule has to be followed for chanting the 'Hare Krishna' Mahamantra:

> ihA hote sarva-siddhi hoibe sabAr/sarva-kshan balo ethe nAhi vidhi Aar// meaning: This [Mahamantra] will give you all what you want.**Just chant it all the time and there is no other rule to be followed** (Sri Chaitanya-BhAgavata).

In Sri Chaitanya CharitAmrita also He says

> diksha-purascharyA vidhi apekshA nA kare/jihva-sparshe Achandal sabAre uddhAre// meaning that for chanting of the Mahamantra one does not need any initiation or 'purascharana'. **Just uttering is enough to get liberation for all the castes.**

So Mahaprabhu also makes it clear that no rule has to be followed at all to chant the Mahamantra.

Reference:MahAmantra-sankirtan,Sitaramdas Omkarnath,Omkarnath Rachanavali, Vol.14, page 264-311.

**UPDATE**

The entire Kali-Santarana-Upanishad can be downloaded from here.Those who think that the word 'Braahmana' is NOT there, may please check this.The one from which I quoted also contains 'Braahmanah' : https://freehindipustak.blogspot.com/2018/05/kalisantaran-upanishad-hindi-sanskrit.html

Comment: _It is a Veda-mantra and especially specified for the brahmins._ No

Comment: @KrishnaShweta i hv told u before this.Both Sri Omkarnathji and Principal Radhagovinda Nath quote the entire Upanishad with 'brahmanah' mentioned explicitly. May be other versions do not mention it is not important to me.And anyhow Mahaprabhu's opinion is final here Who made it public

Comment: @KrishnaShweta And pl remember Radhagovinda was a great scholar vaishnava and a D.Lit. and Omkarnathji was avrenowned saint

Comment: Good answer. How many times per day we should chant the mantra ? I know from the answer we can chant all time but just want to know is there minimum times repetition is there @Pratimaputra

Comment: @AkshayS the Kali-Santara-Upanishad says 'sArdha-tri-koti' times ie 'threecrores and fifty lakh times' :)

Comment: @AkshayS in Total

Comment: Yes, you told me earlier but we have no proof for calling that upanishad as interpolated. One or two scholars cited, that doesn't mean they are true and upanishad is not. Hence whenever anyone says it is for brahmins, I will comment the same.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta r u depending on the internet version alone or have seen this in printed form? Its NOT just two scholars.'Mahamantra -Sankirtan' is a compilation and many famous scholar quote thevword 'brahmana'!

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Some names are Yogendranath Tarka-Samkhya-Vedanta-Tirtha, Kedarnath Sankhyatirtha, Srijiva Nyatirtha etc all mentioned the word 'Brahmana'. They are very renowned scholars and have got many national awards!!

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Also, pl see my update